# MathJax hotkeys script for Chrome and Firefox+Greasemonkey

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Tired of all the dollar and backslash typing? Annoyed of seeing italic units? This may be **THE END OF ALL YOUR PROBLEMS!**

Manishearth INC.\$^{\mathrm{TM}}\$ has created [this fantastic script](https://stackapps.com/q/3373/10098) which will do all (well, almost) the job for you!

No more tired fingers, no more sloppy units, no more slow typing...**ALL THE POWER OF HOTKEYS**!

[Serious mode: ON]

It's a script that Manishearth from Physics.SE created for helping in inserting formulas. It adds both hotkeys and editor buttons to quickly insert math and inline math objects, and also for the `mathrm{}` command, which shall be used for inserting units (so you're not justified for being lazy!).

It can be installed from [here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js), and it's also available as [source code](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/blob/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js). But for using in Firefox you need [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/it/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

If you want you can also donate at me ;). (Whoops, I was in serious mode, wasn't I?)

Comment: Note that inserting unicode characters for units is preferred over MathJax as it loads faster.

Comment: @tyblu true, but it's not very consistent with the formula then..

Comment: I would say that if you don't need MathJax and just need a unit, then use unicode. If you already have other MathJax then might as well use the units in MathJax.

Comment: If you're just putting units in plain text, use AHK shortcuts to insert Unicode units:  https://gist.github.com/823381  Type `kohm` and it becomes `kΩ`, in any text field in any application.

Comment: Just installed it and I get nothing added to the edit box, any ideas?

Comment: @endolith - tried using your script and it does not encode correctly for me. For instance the `mohm` turns into `mÎ©;`. I have tried messing around with encodings but I can't seem to get it to work. The only thing that works is using e.g. `:c1*:kohm::k&Omega;`, but then that wouldn't work elsewhere. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: @OliGlaser: oh oops, it probably requires the unicode L version http://l.autohotkey.net/

Comment: @endolith - ahh, thanks for the quick reply, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @endolith - that sorted it, working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### Note to users who installed it before 5/5/12 (3:51 PM UTC):

The script no longer needs to be updated (most updates include the addition of more sites/buttons and tweaks like tooltips). It auto-fetches the updates now.

I suggest you uninstall/reinstall it to run this one-time update

How to uninstall:

- Chrome: Settings>Tools>Extensions. Find the script and delete it
- Firefox: Open the GM settings and remove the script

Then re-install normally ([click here](https://github.com/Manishearth/Manish-Codes/raw/master/StackExchange/MathJaxButtons.user.js))